# Another characterisation of closed functions

Tags: general-topology

$f:(X,\mathcal{T}_X)\mapsto (Y,\mathcal{T}_Y)$ is closed function if and only if for every topological space $(Z,\mathcal{T}_Z)$ and every continuous $1-1$ function $g:Y \mapsto Z$ the function $g \circ f:X \mapsto Z$ is closed function.

I have shown the inverse direction, but how one shows that $g(f(F))$ is a closed subset of $Z$?

Comment: Reverse direction is trivial. Just use the identity on $Y$ as $g$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true.
For instance take $X=Y=[0,2\pi)$, $f:x\mapsto x$ and $Z = S^1=\{z\in \mathbf C : |z| = 1\}$ and $g : x\mapsto e^{ix}$